# Is Hezbollah officially supported by Iran?

Tags: iran, policy, hezbollah

Does Iran officially support Hezbollah? I have found many pro-Western websites which say that they do, but I can't find any official statements.

So, does Iran *officially* support Hezbollah? If they don't support them officially, then what what evidence is there that Iran supports Hezbollah at all?

Comment: Worth clarification - do you want official policy of Iran supporting Hezbollah, or would the use of Iranian supplied weaponry and military advisors be enough (I e. Unofficial but undeniable support)?

Comment: Yes @Displayname I want to ask, that does Iran OFFICIALLY supports Hezbollah, if not, then what thing shows that it is?

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the question. If you would like to answer, please post a real answer which adheres to our quality standards. Also note that the question asks for *official* support. The fact that Hezbollah unofficially receives logistic support from Iran is an open secret. The question asks for official statements from the Iranian government about their relationship with Hezbollah.

Comment: @phillipp indeed, which is why I didn't turn it into an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hardly a secret that Iran provides money, weapons, training, and direction to Hezbollah.  E.g. as reported in [Hezbollah Admits, “We Take Orders From Iran” | theTrumpet.com](https://www.thetrumpet.com/3586-hezbollah-admits-we-take-orders-from-iran), 2007-04-27:

> A Hezbollah official admitted on Iranian television that his organization receives approval for its terrorist attacks from spiritual leaders in Iran.
>
> April 15, on Iranian TV station “al Qawthar,” the deputy secretary-general of Lebanon-based Hezbollah, Naim Kassem, revealed to an interviewer that Tehran’s ayatollahs must approve acts of violence including suicide bombings and rocket attacks. The admission provided frank public confirmation of a reality long understood in intelligence circles.
>
> …
>
> > The religious doctrine which dictates Hezbollah’s actions in general
> >     and those relating to the Jihad in particular, is based on the rulings
> >     of the spiritual leader in Tehran. The spiritual leader has the power
> >     to permit our actions, and the spiritual leader can forbid them. In
> >     order to know what is permitted and forbidden regarding the Jihad, we
> >     ask for and receive overall permission and only then do we carry out
> >     the operation. Even with regard to the suicide bombings, no one is
> >     allowed to kill himself without religious authorization. Even the
> >     rocket attacks on Israel, against the civilian population [August
> >     2006] … in order to apply pressure, even this required overall
> >     religious authorization.

Iranian television would hardly have played this interview without full Iranian government approval.

---

For those concerned that the above is taken from a religious-based magazine, the same information is available in the [National Review](https://www.nationalreview.com/corner/hezbollah-course-we-get-our-marching-orders-iran-andrew-c-mccarthy/), with the original English translation being an [Israeli news release](https://mfa.gov.il/mfa/foreignpolicy/issues/pages/hizbullah%20leader-%20we%20get%20our%20orders%20from%20teheran%2022-apr-2007.aspx).

So you have three potentially biased news sources to choose from.

Comment: The ultimate [source](https://mfa.gov.il/mfa/foreignpolicy/issues/pages/hizbullah%20leader-%20we%20get%20our%20orders%20from%20teheran%2022-apr-2007.aspx) of that quote seems to be the Israeli government, in its English version anyway. It doesn't appear to have been covered by anymore mainstream media than the religiously oriented "The Trumpet". Actually, the pro-Trump "National Review" covered it too: https://www.nationalreview.com/corner/hezbollah-course-we-get-our-marching-orders-iran-andrew-c-mccarthy/